# jq construct key and value pair

Tags: json, jq

I have JSON file as below:

```
{
   "metadata":{
      "selfLink":"/api/v1/nodes",
      "resourceVersion":"6666628"
   },
   "items":[
      {
         "metadata":{
            "name":"d50d-sa-app23",
            "selfLink":"/api/v1/nodes/d50d-sa-app23",
            "uid":"86a0e0b7-e9da-4489-86bd-0b6a7aafe102",
            "resourceVersion":"6666622",
            "creationTimestamp":"2020-07-07T12:34:08Z",
            "labels":{
               "beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64",
               "beta.kubernetes.io/os":"linux",
               "node-role.kubernetes.io/master":""
            }
          }
      }
    ]
}
```

The desired output is below. **Please note that the name and number of label are not fixed.**

```
beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64;beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux;node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
```

I know how to get keys and values pair separately. like below, but I don't know to pair key & value together.

```
.items[] | ((.metadata.labels | keys | join(",")) + "=" + (.metadata.labels | join(";")))
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you solve your issue:

```
jq -r '.items[].metadata.labels| to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value)") |join(";")'
// Output:
// beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64;beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux;node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
```